# Mysql2::Error sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting $end near ', @@SESSION.sql_auto_is_null = 0

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx, mysql2

So, I have Rails app with MySQL server. I have Sphinx, Thinking Sphinx and MySQL2-gem installed. I then proceeded to create a search form for Sphinx search:

```
<%= form_for(@posts) do |d| %>
```

All good so far. Until I got hit with an error message (resulting from creating that form specifically. I already had my MySQL server running and my app using it.)

```
Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1'
```

Sure. It was obviously a port issue on `config/database.yml` so I switched it from:

```
development:
...
...
host: localhost
```

to:

```
development:
...
...
host: 127.0.0.1
```

And well, it apparently now finds the server, but throws an error:

```
Mysql2::Error
sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting $end near ',   @@SESSION.sql_auto_is_null = 0, @@SESSION.wait_timeout = 2147483, @@SESSION.sql_mode = 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES''
```

And I have literally no idea what that means.

I checked the files indicated in the first lines of full trace:

```
activerecord (4.0.0)     lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:284:in `query'
activerecord (4.0.0)   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:284:in `execute'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:220:in `execute'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:778:in    `configure_connection'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:265:in `configure_connection'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:38:in `initialize'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:20:in `new'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:20:in `mysql2_connection'
```

I checked the files, and they didn't even have any of the values mentioned. This just baffles my mind. Mind also, that those files are at least few months old, and given no errors until now.

All ideas are welcome. I'm very new to MySQL and even Sphinx, so I don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

mysql2 is obviouslly trying to set a bunch of session varibles when it first connects to the server (it obviouslly expects it to be a mysql server, so would understand that query)

Sphinx is not mysql and doesnt understand many mysql commands.

Maybe you can use 
https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/8346
to tell mysql2 not to try to send all these pointless vaiables to the sphinx server.

Answer (score 0):

Something odd is going on - the error you're getting is from Sphinx, and yet the stack trace is from ActiveRecord, not Thinking Sphinx.

Can you confirm that you've not set the port in `config/database.yml` for your development environment to 9306, which is Sphinx's default port?